# How to add or check-in all files in a directory to CVS?

Tags: bash, script, cvs

Say I have a lot of files that I want to add then check in at once. But consider that CVS folder should be excluded. What kind of  command or script can be used in order to do this?

I have tried

```
find -name "*" -type f | xargs cvs add
```

to add files to repository, but it does not work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to find all files in the current directory and add them to cvs:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cvs add {} \;
```

Another set to consider as arguments to find would be `-not -name CVS` if you wanted to exclude something by name (not necessary above because we are only looking at files, not folders).

Comment: But why xargs does not work?

Comment: Likely because of issues with spaces in filenames. You have to be very careful how you use xargs. `find […]|xargs -n1 -iX "X" cvs add` might have worked by running one argument at a time and making sure it was quoted. Using `-exec` is an easier way to avoid that mess.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like:

```
find . -type f -a ! -wholename "*/CVS/*" -print0 | xargs -0 cvs add
```